# C# MongoDB driver 2.4 - How to add a GeoSpatial index

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing, geospatial, mongodb-.net-driver

I upgraded my MongoDB-C# driver, and I couldn't find information about how to create a GeoSpatial index. I have seen many posts using `collection.EnsureIndex`, but I don't have that available. 
I used to use the following, where '`collection`' is `IMongoCollection<>`:

```
collection.CreateIndex((new IndexKeysBuilder().GeoSpatialSpherical("Location")));
```

What is the new way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
var index = Builders<YourCollectionClass>.IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere("Location");
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(index);
// or async version
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  IndexKeysDefinition<DBGeoObject> keys = "{ location: \"2dsphere\" }";
  var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<DBGeoObject>(keys);

  _geoCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
```

You'll have as a result:

[image]